# How to track duration of insertionSort Algorithm Implementation in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, insertion-sort

I'd need some help with Implementation of insertionSort Algorithm in Java.
I have a huge file containing a `BigInteger` in each row. This file's size is about 250 MB.
My aim is to store those values in an `ArrayList<BigInteger>` and then sort that `ArrayList` using insertionSort developed as below:

```
    /**
 * Method insertionSort
 * This method sorts ArrayList list made of generic T elements
 * @param list the ArrayList to be sorted
 */
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void insertionSort(ArrayList<T> list){
    T temp;
    int position;
    for(int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++){
        temp = list.get(i);
        position = i;
        while(position > 0 && list.get(position-1).compareTo(temp) > 0){
            //Shift bigger values to the right
            list.set(position, list.get(position-1));
            position--;
        }
        list.set(position, temp);
    }
}
```

I also need to keep track of duration of sorting method. As Example: 
Let's say `x` is the percentage of sorting completed and `y` the amount of seconds the Method needed to do its job.

```
while(method is sorting){
    System.out.println("Sorting started...");
    ***Sorting in Progress***
    System.out.println("Method has sorted x% of ArrayList");
    ***Sorting Method keeps doing its job***
    System.out.println("Method has sorted x% of ArrayList");
    ***Sorting Method keeps doing its job***
    System.out.println("Method has sorted 100% of ArrayList");
    System.out.println("It took y seconds to sort the provided ArrayList");
}
```

Now my question is: How can I keep track of duration of this algorithm and percentage of completed sorting while method is running?
Hope I've been clear and you guys can help me.
Thank you

Comment: 250MB - how many records are there? Using insertion sort on a large number of records may take too long to complete within a reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a complete solution, with percentage logging and time measurement:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class App {
    /**
     * Method insertionSort
     * This method sorts ArrayList list made of generic T elements
     * @param list the ArrayList to be sorted
     */
    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void insertionSort(List<T> list){
        T temp;
        int position;
        int size = list.size();
        for(int i = 1; i < size; i++){
            temp = list.get(i);
            position = i;
            while(position > 0 && list.get(position-1).compareTo(temp) > 0){
                //Shift bigger values to the right
                list.set(position, list.get(position-1));
                position--;
            }
            list.set(position, temp);
            System.out.println("Sorting... " + ((double)i/(double)size)*100.0 + "%");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(10,6,3,8,1,7,2,9,5,4));

        App.insertionSort(list);

        Double secondsLenght = (System.nanoTime()-startTime)/ Math.pow(10, 9);

        System.out.println(list);
        System.out.println("Sorting took " + secondsLenght + " seconds.");

    }
}
```

Some additional comments:

- Why should you implement your own sorting algorithm?
- You should change the signature for the `insertionSort` method to `insertionSort(List<T> list)`, to make it independent of the `List` implementation.
- Instead of doing `println` inside the function, you should implement some sort of callback that does the updating.

Answer (score 0):

You can track a duration with this code, in my example in seconds:

```
long start = System.nanoTime(); //you take the instant when the operation is starting
//here is where the code will do stuff
Double secondsLenght = (System.nanoTime()-start)/ Math.pow(10, 9); //this is for capturing the result in seconds
```

You can then get intermediate status using this, and calculating the percentage based on your variable, in your example, `list.size()` and `position`